# Is it bad to have unused fields in an OpenGL vertex definition?

Tags: opengl

I define my vertices as below. However, I do not always use all the fields. For example, when drawing a plain triangle, the texture coordinates would not be used.

Now of course everything works fine, but is it more efficient to define another kind of vertex that does not have the texture coordinates?

```
struct Vertex
{
    struct
    {
        float x, y, z;  // World Coordinates, z is the depth
        float s0, t0;   // Texture coordinate
        unsigned char r, g, b, a;   // tint
        float padding[2];  // AMD says pad to 32 (edit)BYTE, boundary
    };
};
```

Comment: You don't need those padding fields: sizeof(float) = 4 bytes, sizeof(unsigned char) = 1 byte, thus 5*4 + 4*1 = 24 = 3 * 2^3 bytes; 1 byte = 8 bit (on most plattforms) i.e = 3 * 2^3 * 2^3 = 3 * 2^6 bits = 3*2 * 2^5 bits = 6 * 32 bits. i.e. you're on the 6th 32 bit boundary without that padding.

Comment: @datenwolf He probably meant 32 byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that's fine.  Being 16- or 32-byte aligned is usually more of a win than minimizing memory footprint.

Comment: But if some of his meshes don't have textures, a vertex+color only format would also be nice for those, since it's already 16-byte aligned without any padding.